# Excel - How to count unique days in a list a duplicated days

Tags: excel, list, date, formula, days

Having a list of days suchs as:

```
01-giu-16
01-giu-16
01-giu-16
31-mag-16
31-mag-16
31-mag-16
31-mag-16
30-mag-16
```

I was looking for an excel formula that helps me count the number of unique days in the list (in this example 3)

Moreover I need the count only for the dates which have a specific ID in the next column (for example 1565)

Comment: 1st question, are the dates stored as excel date time serials?  when you change the cell format to general do they show a number like 4265?  or if you prefer, `=isnumber(A1)` , where A1 is one of the dates, does it return true?

Comment: Will your dates always be grouped or sorted?

Comment: not grouped/sorted list and they are cell number

Comment: There is a big difference between sorting dates as you have show in your example and sorting and counting text or numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Without any additional criteria, you can achieve the uniqueness count by using

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8))`, assuming your data are in the range `A1:A8`.

To evaluate subject to additional criteria (suppose they are in column B), use

`{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B1:B8=1565,MATCH(A1:A8,A1:A8,0)),ROW(A1:A8)-ROW(A1)+1)>0))}`

This is an *array* formula: use Ctrl + Shift + Return once you're done editing (and don't type the curly braces yourself). Personally though I think this exceeds the reasonable threshold for complexity: I'd be inclined to adopt the first approach on a column that represents an intermediate transformation of your input data.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your data is in Column A and it has a header row.  So the first data number will actually be in A2.  Place this formula in B2 and copy down beside your list.  It will generate a list of unique cell numbers from column A.  Once you have the list you simply need to use a function to count the side of it.

```
=iferror(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$5),0,0),0)),"")
```

in C2 you can use the following formula to get the number of unique cell numbers

```
=COUNTA(B2:B9)-COUNTIF(B2:B9,"")
```

In D2 you can use the following formula to get the count of each unique cell number from your original list.  Copy it down as far as you need to go.

```
=IF(B5="","",COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,B5))
```